# Can you apply a core image filter to a live camera view?

Tags: ios, filter, camera, ciimage

I use the below function to display a live camera view onto an iPhone screen.

Does anyone know how I can apply a core image filter to it, such as comic, or sepia, etc?

```
    func showCameraVC() {
        self.myLiveCameraView = UIImagePickerController()

        if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.front) {
            self.myLiveCameraView?.sourceType = .camera
            self.myLiveCameraView?.cameraDevice = .front
            self.myLiveCameraView?.showsCameraControls = false
                    
            let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
            let cameraAspectRatio = CGFloat(4.0 / 3.0)
            let cameraImageHeight = screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio
            let scale = screenSize.height / cameraImageHeight
            self.myLiveCameraView?.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: (screenSize.height - cameraImageHeight)/2)
            self.myLiveCameraView?.cameraViewTransform = self.myLiveCameraView!.cameraViewTransform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
        
            self.myLiveCameraView?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width / 2, height: screenSize.height / 2)
            self.view.addSubview(self.myLiveCameraView!.view)
            self.myLiveCameraView!.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            self.myLiveCameraView!.view.layer.borderWidth = 0
            self.myLiveCameraView!.view.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    } // ends showCameraVC
```